# Creating a method with Reflection.Emit, and then invoking it

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, reflection, reflection.emit

This sounds like such an obvious thing but I am having a lot of difficulty. Basically, what I'm doing is generating a method using Reflection.Emit and I then want to call it. So far, I have the method building and such, but I can't get a reference to the method after it's built because "The invoked member is not supported before the type is created."

Here is what I basically do:

```
AssemblyBuilder assembly;
ModuleBuilder module;
TypeBuilder containerTypeBuilder;
Type containerType;
var name = new AssemblyName();
name.Name = "DynamicWrapper";
var domain = Thread.GetDomain();
assembly = domain.DefineDynamicAssembly(name, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
module = assembly.DefineDynamicModule(assembly.GetName().Name, false);
containerTypeBuilder = module.DefineType("__DynamicWrapperType",
                              TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class |
                              TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
                              TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
                              TypeAttributes.AutoLayout, typeof(object));
//build method
var mb = containerTypeBuilder.DefineMethod("generatedmethod" + (unique++),
                              MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, typeof (int),
                              new Type[] {});
//build method body and all that
.....
var type=module.GetType("__DynamicWrapperType");
var info=type.GetMethod(mb.Name, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public); //error here
```

How do I take my freshly built method and load it up so that I can invoke it?

Also, I've tried `mb.Invoke`, but that yields "The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic module."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are creating individual method(s), then `DynamicMethod` is a much better choice (especially since your method is static) - you just use`CreateDelegate` (specifying the delegate type), *cast* to that delegate, and invoke. It is also less overhead, and collectible.

But if you are forced to use `MethodBuilder`: you must use `CreateType` on the `TypeBuilder`, then use reflection on the now *real* type (returned from `CreateType`).

Comment: Not sure why I didn't consider DynamicMethod from the beginning. I'll see if that will work (It's just for unit testing, so not hugely important to be collectable, but it sounds easier to use)

Comment: @Earlz it is **much** easier: no AssemblyBuilder, ModuleBuilder, AssemblyName, TypeBuilder, MethodBuilder - basically just ILGenerator.

Comment: Yea, just converted to using DynamicMethod in about 2 seconds and got this all fixed :) Now just to find what makes my IL throw an invalid program exception

Comment: @Earlz usually: unbalanced stack, for example an Add that returns a value you don't need (in which case, add a "pop"). Let me know if you want me to take a look... I've done plenty of ILGenerator